# クロージャ内で指定したdelegateでイベントが拾えない

Tags: swift

APIを叩いた後にアラートを出し、そのイベントを拾ってから次のイベントに進みたいのですが、クロージャ内で`delegate: self`を指定しても、イベントが拾われません。
Objective-Cは触っておらず、swiftも初心者なので解決法が浮かばずに困っております。

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (result: Bool?) -> Void

class hogeViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    var completion: CompletionHandler?

    func test(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void) {

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: apiUrl)!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in

            let alert = UIAlertView(
                message: testMessage
                delegate: self,
                cancelButtonTitle: nil,
                otherButtonTitles: "test1", "test2")
            alert.show()
            return
        })
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("clickedButtonAtIndex")
        println(buttonIndex)

        self.completion!(result: true)
    }
}
```

お詳しい方がいましたらご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

コンパイルが通らなかったので細部を直しましたが、私の環境ではちゃんとUIAlertViewのボタンイベントが拾われました。
環境：iPhone6（iOS8.1.3）

ちなみに UIAlertView はiOS8から非推奨なので、iOS8以上なら代わりにUIAlertControllerを使うことを推奨します。

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (result: Bool?) -> Void

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    let apiUrl = "https://www.google.co.jp"

    var completion: CompletionHandler? = {(result: Bool?) in
        println("API completed! \(result)")
    }

    func test() {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: apiUrl)!)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) in

            let alert = UIAlertView(
                title: "アラートのタイトル",
                message: "アラートのメッセージ",
                delegate: self,
                cancelButtonTitle: nil,
                otherButtonTitles: "test1", "test2")
            alert.show()
            return
        })
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        println("clickedButtonAtIndex")
        println(buttonIndex)

        self.completion?(result: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます！

説明不足ですみません。
実際は別のViewから下記のように呼び出しているのですが、呼び出し方が悪いのでしょうか？
`hogeViewController().test { (result: Bool) -> () in println(result)  }  `

iOS7以上をターゲットにしているため、今回はUIAlertViewで作成しています。

Comment: `hogeViewController()`とインスタンスを生成しただけでは、画面上に現れません。pushViewController〜なり、presentViewController〜なりしないと。あるいは、生成したhogeViewControllerのインスタンスと、既存のhogeViewControllerのインスタンスは、別物ですよ。すくなくともイニシアライザ`hogeViewController()`を使っては、「呼び出し」ていることにはなりません。

Comment: @koux2ともかく、問題のポイントが、提示されたコード外の箇所にありそうな流れなので、質問内容を再編集し、「 **確実に問題が発生する** 」コードに書きかえることをお勧めします。